# List Content types not getting updating while adding a site column to already deployed site content type using elements.xml

Tags: 2013, content-type, column, elements-xml

I have a site content type deployed through element.xml and is used inside lists. I added one site column and referenced that in content type. So my element.xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{03261118-F31C-4611-87AA-D581E2F1B26D}" Name="A"  StaticName="A" Group="A" Type="Text" DisplayName="A" MaxLength="50" />
  <Field ID="{D1206865-904E-4EF2-BE89-DC91DF70921A}" Name="B" StaticName="B" Group="B" Type="Text" DisplayName="B" MaxLength="10" />
  <ContentType ID="0x0101003240568bb942457a80e5c067f05048120001bc650de70a44d496897008e3525c59"
               Name="XYZ"
               Group="XYZ"
               Description="XYZ"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{03261118-F31C-4611-87AA-D581E2F1B26D}" Name="A"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{D1206865-904E-4EF2-BE89-DC91DF70921A}" Name="B"/>      
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

where column A was already there and deployed and column B is added later. When i redeploy the wsp i can see the column B added in site columns but was not added to XYZ content type. When i try to added it manually using User Interface, changes get propogate to child content types, but not to list content types.

Please help.